# Simulate Proximity Sensor (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, xcode, proximity

Is there any way to simulate the use of the proximity sensor using the iOS simulator? I don't have the certificate yet to test on a device, so I need some way of simulating the proximity sensor returning yes or no for testing a function.

So, can I simulate it, or do I have to wait for the certificate? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, unfortunately you can't simulate it.